# plot..circle not working when x-axis has string categories

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

My data has categorical variables of "string" dtype on x-axis. Is it possible to plot circles on my line-graph points with bokeh?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure(x_range=['a', 'b', 'c'])
ds = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=list('aaabbbccc'), y=list(range(9))))
p.line('x', 'y', source=ds)
p.circle('x', 'y', source=ds, color='red', size=20)

show(p)
```